# Fixing numpy array after reading in text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in a text file and format it correctly in a numpy array.

The Input.txt file contains:

```
 point_load, 3, -300

 point_load, 6.5, 500

 point_moment, 6.5, 3000
```

I want to produce this array:

```
 point_load = [3, -300, 65, 500]
```

My code is:

```
 a = []
 for line in open("Input.txt"):
     li=line.strip()
     if li.startswith("point_load")
          a.append(li.split(","))

 #np.flatten(a)
```

My code prints:

```
 [['point_load', '     3', '          -300'], ['point_load', '     6.5', '         500']]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
a.append(li.split(","))
```

to this:

```
a.append(li.split(",")[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

To end up with a list of numbers instead of strings, I recommend the following:

```
a = []
for line in open("Input.txt"):
    li=line.strip()
    if li.startswith("point_load"):
        l = li.split(',')
        for num in l[1:]:
            try:
                num = float(num.strip())
                a.append(num)
            except ValueError:
                print 'num was not a number'
```

The difference here is the list slice which takes the entire line starting from the second comma-separated element (more here: [understanding-pythons-slice-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation))

```
l[1:]
```

Also, stripping then converting the strings to floats (since you have decimals)

```
num = float(num.strip())
```

Resulting array:

```
a = [3.0, -300.0, 6.5, 500.0]
```

Comment: When running this, sometimes I get the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'end'. After searching, I cant find much on this. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: This means the string it is trying to convert to float is not actually composed of digits. You could place this conversion in a try-except (I edited the code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

```
li.split(",")
```

returns a *list*, so you appended a *list*, obtaining a *nested list*.

You wanted append *individual elements* append to the `a` list, namely 2nd and 3rd, i. e. with indices `1` and `2`. So instead

```
a.append(li.split(","))
```

use

```
temp = li.split(","))
second = temp[1]
third  = temp[2]
a.append(float(second))
a.append(float(third))
```

Note the use of the `float()` function as the `.split()` method returns a list of *strings*.
(Maybe in the last `.append()` would be more appropriate for you the use of `int()` function instead.)